# Pandas Dataframe: Split a column into multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a pandas `dataframe` with columns names as: (columns type as `Object`)

```
1. x_id
2. y_id
3. Sentence1
4. Sentences2
5. Label
```

I want to separate sentences1 and sentence2 into multiple columns in same `dataframe`.

Here is an example: `dataframe` names as df

```
x_id     y_id     Sentence1          Sentence2          Label
0        2        This is a ball     I hate you         0
1        5        I am a boy         Ahmed Ali          1
2        1        Apple is red       Rose is red        1
3        9        I love you so much Me too             1
```

After splitting the columns[Sentence1,Sentence2] by ' ' Space, `dataframe` looks like:

```
x_id     y_id     1     2     3    4     5      6      7     8      Label
0        2        This  is    a    ball  NONE   I      hate  you    0
1        5        I     am    a    boy   NONE   Ahmed  Ali   NONE   1
2        1        Apple is    red  NONE  NONE   Rose   is    red    1
3        9        I     love  you  so    much   Me     too   NONE   1
```

How to split the columns like this in `python`? How to do this using `pandas dataframe`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One-hot-encoding labeling solution:

```
In [14]: df.Sentence1 += ' ' + df.pop('Sentence2')

In [15]: df
Out[15]:
   x_id  y_id                  Sentence1  Label
0     0     2  This is a ball I hate you      0
1     1     5       I am a boy Ahmed Ali      1
2     2     1   Apple is red Rose is red      1
3     3     9  I love you so much Me too      1

In [16]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

In [17]: vect = CountVectorizer()

In [18]: X = vect.fit_transform(df.Sentence1.fillna(''))
```

`X` - is a sparsed (memory saving) matrix:

```
In [23]: X
Out[23]:
<4x17 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 19 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [24]: type(X)
Out[24]: scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix

In [19]: X.toarray()
Out[19]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

Most of sklearn methods accept sparsed matrixes.

If you want to "unpack" it:

```
In [21]: r = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns=vect.get_feature_names())

In [22]: r
Out[22]:
   ahmed  ali  am  apple  ball  boy  hate  is  love  me  much  red  rose  so  this  too  you
0      0    0   0      0     1    0     1   1     0   0     0    0     0   0     1    0    1
1      1    1   1      0     0    1     0   0     0   0     0    0     0   0     0    0    0
2      0    0   0      1     0    0     0   2     0   0     0    2     1   0     0    0    0
3      0    0   0      0     0    0     0   0     1   1     1    0     0   1     0    1    1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [26]: x = pd.concat([df.pop('Sentence1').str.split(expand=True),
    ...:                df.pop('Sentence2').str.split(expand=True)],
    ...:               axis=1)
    ...:

In [27]: x.columns = np.arange(1, x.shape[1]+1)

In [28]: x
Out[28]:
       1     2    3     4     5      6     7     8
0   This    is    a  ball  None      I  hate   you
1      I    am    a   boy  None  Ahmed   Ali  None
2  Apple    is  red  None  None   Rose    is   red
3      I  love  you    so  much     Me   too  None

In [29]: df = df.join(x)

In [30]: df
Out[30]:
   x_id  y_id  Label      1     2    3     4     5      6     7     8
0     0     2      0   This    is    a  ball  None      I  hate   you
1     1     5      1      I    am    a   boy  None  Ahmed   Ali  None
2     2     1      1  Apple    is  red  None  None   Rose    is   red
3     3     9      1      I  love  you    so  much     Me   too  None
```

Comment: Expand is Great on split +1

Comment: @pansen Thanks :) this code works fine on small dataset But hang/halt on large amount of data, about 700000 dataset. there is an efficient way to improve this code in term of performance.

Comment: @AAKM, what are you going to do with this transformed data set? I got a feeling that edouard was ritght. Maybe you want to make "one-hot-encoding"? In this case there are much more efficient methods and techniques to do so...

Comment: @MaxU can you give me name of those techniques and how to implement that techniques?

Comment: @AAKM, i'm not pansen, but i'll try to answer your question ;-)

Comment: @AAKM, in order to give you a helpful answer I must understand what are you trying to achieve. That's why I asked you: `"what are you going to do with this transformed data set?"` - can you answer that question?

Comment: @MaxU I only want to split this data and apply `label encoding` row wise in python using `dataframe` and `sklearn`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139680/discussion-between-aak-m-and-maxu).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it for the sentences in the column `Sentence1`. The idea is identical for the `Sentence2` column.

```
splits = df.Sentence1.str.split(' ')
longest = splits.apply(len).max()
```

Note that `longest` is the length of the longest sentence. Now make the Null columns:

```
for j in range(1,longest+1):
    df[str(j)] = np.nan
```

And finally, go through the splitted values and assign them:

```
for j in splits.values:
    for k in range(1,longest+1):
        try:
            df.loc[str(j), k] = j[k]
        except:
            pass
```

`

Comment: What is `temp`? If `temp` is a **variable** that its undefined and not assign.

Comment: @AAKM Error, fixed it.

Comment: this code is not working as i needed. but thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a machine learning problem. Converting from 1 col to max words columns this way may not be efficient.

Another (probably more efficient) solution is converting each words to integer and then padding to the longest sentences. `Tensorflow` as tools for that.

Comment: No I want to split dataframe explain above. I need to perform some other techniques to this Data set. If you have a code kindly share it, it might help me.

Comment: OK. It was just a suggestion.

Comment: I only want to split this data and apply `label encoding` row wise in python using `dataframe` and `sklearn`